# Uploading to S3: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want upload object Data to my AWS S3 bucket from react. But I get this error while doing it:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split').

If I try to upload only the Image it works fine. Is it possible to upload data like this or is S3 just for images?

```
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import S3 from 'react-aws-s3';

function App() {

  window.Buffer = window.Buffer || require("buffer").Buffer;
  const config={
    bucketName: "bucket_name",
    region: "eu-west-2",
    dirName: "dire",
    accessKeyId: "accessKeyID",
    secretAccessKey: "secretAccessKey",
}


  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState(null);
  const initialStatus = {
    fileUrl :'',
    fileName: ''
  }
  const [objData, setobjectData] = useState(initialStatus)
  console.log(objData)
  const handleFileInput = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setobjectData({
      fileUrl: URL.createObjectURL(file),
      fileName: file.name
    })
  }
  

  const handleUpload = async (file) => {
    console.log(file)
    const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);
    ReactS3Client
        .uploadFile(file, "MyImage")
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <div>React S3 File Upload</div>
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInput}/>
        <button onClick={() => handleUpload(objData)}> Upload to S3</button>
        
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Amazon S3 works with any type of file. Which line generated the error?

Comment: ReactS3Client
        .uploadFile(file, "MyImage")
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.error(err)  this is the line that generates the error